# Jquery not adding or Removing my selected class for my nav menu

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I wrote my site with php. I have the index file dynamically loading my pages from a pages folder. I have the nav menu in a separate file as well.

so I'm trying to have the text color highlighted when clicked, since I can't get the windowlocation to work. Because of the way I have it setup, the windowlocation returns /index.php with javascript or jquery. So I tried to keep it simple by just targeting the link.

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?p=home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?p=skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?p=about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Script to add selected class to highlight active link-->    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul li a").click(function(){
        $("ul li a").removeClass('selected');  
        $("ul li a").addClass('selected');
        });
    });
</script>
```

my css is setup like this:

```
a.selected{color:#0066ff;}
```

I've tried throwing this code in every php file I created. Still nothing works. When I want an alert box to pop up with a message when a link is clicked, that works fine. why does this not work? Nothing changes when I run the code... Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are doing a page redirect on the anchor click then it won't work because any dom changes you have done will be lost after page redirect

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Sj9N/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you reload the page by clicking each link then try

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?p=home" <?php (empty($_GET['p']) || $_GET['p'] == 'home') ? echo 'class="selected"' : ''?> >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?p=skills" <?php $_GET['p'] == 'skills' ? echo 'class="selected"' : ''?>>Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?p=about" <?php $_GET['p'] == 'about' ? echo 'class="selected"' : ''?>>About</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?p=contact" <?php $_GET['p'] == 'contact' ? echo 'class="selected"' : ''?> >Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Though you won't need the jQuery function.
If you don't want to reload the page then try this in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li a").click(function(){
       $("ul li a").removeClass('selected');  
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add selected class in the clicked li element.

try like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul li a").click(function(){
        $(".selected").removeClass('selected');  
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

Actually you are redirecting when you are clicking in the li element. so jquery wil not be worked in this scenario.
it will work if you use one page application with out page reloading.
You can to do it by php like this:

// index.php

```
<?php

   $page = isset($_REQUEST['p']) ? $_REQUEST['p'] : '';

switch($page) {
case 'skills' :
  echo ' <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=skills"  class="selected">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>';
   break;

case 'about' :
  echo ' <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=home" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=about"  class="selected">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>';
   break;

case 'contact' :
  echo ' <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=home" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=contact"  class="selected">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>';
   break;

default: 
 echo ' <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>';


}
```

Comment: it won't work because it looks like the anchor click is reloading a new page

Comment: @Arun P Johny : you are right. i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
   $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
   $(this).addClass('current');
});
```